# What does "-" (dash) after color do in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code that draws a graph.
`plt.plot([1,7], [1,1], 'k-', linewidth=2)`
In lines like this, there are `k-` which represents the color black.
However the code works without the dash, so `k` is just fine.

Why is that dash `-` there? What does it do?

I couldn't find anything that explains this. I even read the documentation below.
https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title("Dijkstra")

#plt.plot( [x1, x2], [y1, y2], color, linewidth )
plt.plot([1,7,1,7,9], [5,5,1,1,3], 'ro')

plt.plot([1,1], [1,5], 'r', linewidth=2)
plt.annotate('A', [1,5])
plt.plot([1,7], [1,1], 'k-', linewidth=2)
plt.plot([7,7], [1,5], 'k-', linewidth=2)
plt.plot([1,7], [5,5], 'k-', linewidth=2)
plt.plot([1,7], [1,5], 'k-', linewidth=2)
plt.plot([7,9], [5,3], 'k-', linewidth=2)
plt.plot([7,9], [1,3], 'k-', linewidth=2)

plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 6]) # Set axis values
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dash is the symbol for a solid line. Since it is the default line type, omitting it does not alter the plot.

For more information, see the [line-style reference](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/line_styles_reference.html):

[image: Line styles]